# IE6 box bug with 3 divs layout

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

I have 3 `divs` horizontally within a wrapper div as so:

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div style="float: left;" class="sidebar"></div>
    <div style="float: right;" class="sidebar"></div>
    <div class="main"><img width="636" height="333" /></div>
</div>
```

```css
#wrapper
    width: 940px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-bottom: solid #668ccc 2px;
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;

 div.sidebar{
    border: solid 3px #999;
    width: 126px;
    height: 360px;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px;

 .main {
    width: 636px;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
```

**So here's what's happening:** I have two sidebars and a center div for the pages main content, in this case an image that has a width that is as wide as the center div, its right up to both sidebars on either side of it, so:

```
sidebars: 304px wide,  center div: 636px wide,  Totaling 940px
```

In all modern browsers it shows perfectly, but in **IE6**, the center div is pushed down as if the two sidebars are actually wider.

I tried removing the padding from the actual sidebars and applying it to the text within but no difference. Also changing to doctype 4.01 strict does nothing (I have doctype *html / html5* by default).

Here's the actual page: http://www.final7fantasy.com/index1.html
And on netrender.com for IE6: http://netrenderer.com/index.php

Comment: Yep, I must be a pretty decent dev to want the best cross compatibility possible in that case.

Comment: [It appears you succeeded in getting this to work](http://i.imgur.com/FWv0lNh.jpg). Would you like to share your solution, or perhaps consider closing the question?